# How do I run a single task in an Airflow DAG more than once?

Tags: airflow

So I have 2 paths and step A and C checks for updates and do some transformations in databases and step E unload a query to an artifact file.

```
A -> B -> 
         --> E
C -> D ->
```

Now I want step E to run when:
1) Step A and B are completed
or 
2) Step C and D are completed

I tried to use trigger_rule 'one_success' in step E, but the problem is that if step A starts just before step C, step E will only run once and the data change in C is not unloaded to the final artifact, missing the desired SLA.

Is there a way in Airflow to force a step to execute once any parent task finish executing, regardless whether it has already been executed? It seems like this is a very logical and common use case, but searching the documentation doesn't yield me anything.

Comment: why not have two identical steps E1 and E2? so you would have A -> B -> E1 and A -> B -> E2

Comment: I definitely can do that, but I essentially need to create 2 identical steps and I want to know whether there is a better way to achieve this in Airflow.